# MalformedPolicy error using aws s3api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to use **put-bucket-policy** to add a policy to an s3 bucket via the aws s3api (Windows).

I am using precisely the policy code given here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_s3_a.html  under "Granting Permission to an Anonymous User" with my bucket name substituted in.

I am getting

```
A client error (MalformedPolicy) occured: policies must be valid JSON and the first byte must be '{'
```

Any clues?

EDIT: Inlining the JSON works- so it is some kind of file format issue - just not one that I can see. Be great to be able to get it working with files.

EDIT: To help anyone else who maybe ends up here, buckets should be named all in lowercase. If not, some s3/s3api operations work, but not others. See [here](http://support.rightscale.com/09-Clouds/AWS/FAQs/FAQ_0094_-_What_are_valid_S3_bucket_names?)

Comment: Sounds like you're not. :)  Try validating your policy document? http://jsonlint.com/  Also seems possible that if your JSON is valid, then the editor you're using is attaching some noise, like a utf BOM to the beginning of the file.

Comment: Already checked on JSONLint - it's valid. Have looked in a hex editor, and cropped an initial coupla bytes, tried making the file UTF-8, Unicode, ANSI. Still the same error.

Comment: When I have to use windows, I use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to edit text, html, perl, json, sql, and no issues when I have to push the files back over to other systems... maybe give that a try?

Comment: I maybe will - it's actually okay inline for this job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone with inling the JSON.

Couple of maybe useful hints for those that end up here.

1. Bucket names: Buckets should be named all in lowercase. If not, some s3/s3api operations work (**mb**, **put-bucket-policy**), but not others **(put-bucket-website**) See [http://support.rightscale.com/09-Clouds/AWS/FAQs/FAQ_0094_-_What_are_valid_S3_bucket_names%3F](http://support.rightscale.com/09-Clouds/AWS/FAQs/FAQ_0094_-_What_are_valid_S3_bucket_names?)
2. If, like me, you start by using **get-bucket-website** on a bucket created through the S3 console to get example JSON for making a bucket a website, it may not work. **get-bucket-website** gives you back blank entries for any unset parameters (e.g. **RedirectAllRequestsTo**) - which gives errors if used in **put-bucket-website**... Just miss parameters out if you don't need them and that works - e.g.

   {"IndexDocument":{"Suffix":"index.html"}}

is the minimum. (remember to escape the quotes if inlining!)

Answer (score 17):

#### TL;DR

You must **add `file://` protocol scheme** to the policy file path

```
$ aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket kryptonite \
   --policy file:///home/superman/aws-example/public-bucket-policy.json
```

OR (**Windows**)

```
$ aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket kryptonite \
   --policy file://C:\Temp\public-bucket-policy.json
```

OR (**relative path**)

```
$ aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket kryptonite \
   --policy file://public-bucket-policy.json
```

#### FULL STORY: How to set public bucket policy via CLI

First let's make sure there's no other policy on the bucket:

```
$ s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket kryptonite

A client error (NoSuchBucketPolicy) occurred when calling the   GetBucketPolicy
   operation: The bucket policy does not exist
```

Now let's make sure we have policy file in current directory and it contains valid json (mind name of the `kryptonite` bucket

```
$ ls
public-bucket-policy.json

$ cat public-bucket-policy.json 
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::kryptonite/*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": "AddPerm"
    }
  ],
  "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Now let's try to put the policy by specifying just filename

```
$ s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket kryptonite --policy public-bucket-policy.json

A client error (MalformedPolicy) occurred when calling the PutBucketPolicy 
   operation: Policies must be valid JSON and the first byte must be '{'
```

Now let's make another attempt and specify the full path
    $ s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket kryptonite \
         --policy /home/superman/aws-example/public-bucket-policy.json

```
A client error (MalformedPolicy) occurred when calling the PutBucketPolicy 
   operation: Policies must be valid JSON and the first byte must be '{'
```

Now let's add `file://` prefix and it will work

```
$ s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket kryptonite \
    --policy file:///home/superman/aws-example/public-bucket-policy.json
```

And we can now verify that this policy had been applied

```
$ s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket kryptonite
{
    "Policy": "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Sid\":\"AddPerm\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"s3:GetObject\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:s3:::kryptonite/*\"}]}"
}
```

And as special bonus let's pipe the policy through the `jq` utility (twice) to extract correct field and format JSON nicely

```
$ s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket kryptonite | jq .Policy --raw-output | jq .
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::kryptonite/*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": "AddPerm"
    }
  ],
  "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

## And as you can see the policy is correct

Comment: Yes ! it worked for me. Missing file:// protocol

Answer (score 0):

For a "full inline" syntax, use :

```
aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket MYBUCKETNAME --policy "{\"Version\":\"2008-10-17\", \"Statement\":[{\"Sid\":\"AllowPublicRead\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"AWS\":\"*\"},\"Action\":\"s3:GetObject\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKETNAME/*\"}]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was not the structure of the json file but the Encoding was UTF-16.
Once I converted it to UTF-8, it solved the problem.